# Initializing Date in Kotlin

Tags: date, kotlin, int

I'm trying to pass a date to a function in Kotlin. I don't want to have to type "08/30/2018" as a String and would instead prefer Date. I initially tried just 08/30/2018 but get a compiler stating an Integer was found for the input rather than Date.

```
var myDate = 1/1/2000
var newDate = 08/30/2018

fun setDate(value: Int){
    myDate = value
}

setDate(newDate)

println(newDate) //0
println(myDate) //0
println(myDate.compareTo(newDate)) //0
```

1. Why does Kotlin accept 08/30/2018 as an int? Why is it stored correctly to another int variable but then print 0 when the value is retrieved?
2. How can I initialize a variable to a date like 1/1/2000 and then set another date later on? I haven't found anything about passing a date anywhere unless it is a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When you assign `8/30/2018` to a variable then the compiler recognizes it as integer division `8/30` which is `0` and then `/2018` and the result is `0`.
2. You could do it like `val date = Date("1/1/2000")` but this is now deprecated

You can use the Java 8 Date/Time API instead:  
`val date = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1)`  
you can find more here:  
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: It might be useful to clarify that 1. `08/30` is already `0`; 2. in many other languages a literal starting with `0` is octal, so `08` would be an error.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov 1. I already edited my answer 2. in Kotlin `var newDate = 08/30/2018` does not even compile, the error is *Error:(373, 20) Kotlin: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)*

Comment: @mobibob can you provide an official link about the deprecation of LocalDate?

Comment: First, it is stated in the answer "but this is now deprecated" and when I tried using it, I received the warning in the Android Studio when integrating with Room framework.  I am not certain I can reconstruct the crime and resolution.

Comment: @mobibob it is [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) that is deprecated, not [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Do you understand the difference?

Comment: -- I am deleting my 1/31/2023 comment; I cannot reproduce how I got to that conclusion from Date -> LocalDate -> Calendar, but I recently completed a DatePicker dialog using LocalDate and storing to/from a Room DB.  I stand corrected and thanks @forpas for pointing it out.